# Repeat the Rectangle in each page in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have rectangle in the body section of SSRS Report.

But the rectangle is displaying in the first page only. not displaying further pages.

Anyone have any idea how to display static data in the body in each page.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have a matrix or a table in the report body or any report item that is repeating in every page, you can set your rectangle's property ***RepeatWith*** to the name of that report item.

for example:

RepeatWith: Matrix_Main

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a new table

2) Deleted header and other columns and keep only one cell in data row of your table.

3) Now right click on the cell > Insert > Rectangle.

4) Now in the table Cell (rectangle cell), insert the static content you need.

5) Set static control Value with DataSet Fields.

finished.

Comment: Worked well with slight variation on matrix - Added row above outside group on header row, placed rectangle in new row.